# Oracle stored procedure json_table giving too many value error

Tags: json, oracle, stored-procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_INTEGRATED_EMPLOYEE ( emp clob ,  id number) IS TYPE EMPLOYEES IS TABLE OF EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE; EMPS EMPLOYEES; BEGIN 
SELECT *  BULK COLLECT INTO EMPS
FROM 
json_table( emp , '$[*]' 
COLUMNS ( FIRSTNAME VARCHAR PATH '$.firstname'));

FOR i IN 1..EMPS.COUNT
    LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(EMPS(i).FIRSTNAME || ' ' || emp);
END LOOP;END;/
```

I have an employee table in my database and i want to map a json array of employee and then print the firstname of all the employee. But this json_table is giving an error statement Error(11,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `EMPLOYEE` table with a single column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (firstname VARCHAR2(20));
```

Then your procedure works.

If you have extra columns:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee ADD lastname VARCHAR2(20);
ALTER PROCEDURE INSERT_INTEGRATED_EMPLOYEE COMPILE;
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

Outputs the errors:

> | NAME | TYPE | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | INSERT_INTEGRATED_EMPLOYEE | PROCEDURE | 1 | 10 | 3 | PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values | ERROR | 0 |
> | INSERT_INTEGRATED_EMPLOYEE | PROCEDURE | 2 | 9 | 3 | PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored | ERROR | 0 |

This is because you define the type and variable:

```sql
TYPE EMPLOYEES IS TABLE OF EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE;
EMPS EMPLOYEES;
```

And if the `EMPLOYEE` table has more than one column and so the `EMPS` variable will be a collection of records each expecting more than one column.

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
BULK COLLECT INTO EMPS
FROM json_table(
       emp,
       '$[*]' 
       COLUMNS ( FIRSTNAME VARCHAR PATH '$.firstname'));
```

Will try to insert a single `firstname` value into the record that expects multiple values.

---

Instead, you can create a table of a single data type (rather than a record):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_INTEGRATED_EMPLOYEE (
  emp clob,
  id number
)
IS
  TYPE firstname_table IS TABLE OF employee.firstname%TYPE;
  EMPS firstname_table;
BEGIN 
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO EMPS
  FROM   json_table(
           emp,
           '$[*]' 
           COLUMNS (
             FIRSTNAME VARCHAR PATH '$.firstname'
           )
         );

  FOR i IN 1..EMPS.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(EMPS(i) || ' ' || emp);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or, use a cursor (rather than a collection):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_INTEGRATED_EMPLOYEE (
  emp clob,
  id  number
)
IS
BEGIN 
  FOR i IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM json_table(
           emp,
           '$[*]' 
           COLUMNS (
             FIRSTNAME VARCHAR PATH '$.firstname'
           )
         )
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(i.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || emp);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc674118d0fa76a9768f05341fdbbf01)*

Comment: When Record expects more than one column , does it expect only non-nullable column or all the columns ?

Comment: @PulkitSharma All the columns

Comment: One more question how can the id attribute will now genrate the unique value or i have to pass it in json object only?